# Web2Py: customizing two-step verification form

Tags: python, html, css, web2py, two-factor-authentication

I want to customize the [two-step verification](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Two-step-verification) form of web2py. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259277/web2py-customizing-auth-forms) question which explains how to customize a normal auth form which was useful, but I still don't know how to use a custom form for the second step (submitting the verification code). Does anyone know how to do this or have already succeeded at this?
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine whether you are on the second step of the login process, you can check the value of `session.auth_two_factor_user` (it will have a value during the second step but be `None` otherwise). So, in the `user.html` view, you could include conditional logic like this:

```
{{if request.args(0) == 'login':}}
  {{if not session.auth_two_factor_user:}}
  [Custom first step login form]
  {{else:}}
  [Custom second step code verification form]
  {{pass}}
{{pass}}
```